# How to read command line arguments in Vertx

Tags: javascript, command-line-arguments, vert.x

I am trying to read command line arguments in `vert.x` with javascript as language. Could you please help me on this. For example how to read

```
arguments(arg1, arg2, arg3)

vertx run example.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you start your verticle with with `vertx run example.js` then the verticle will be deployed by this class: https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/Starter.java

`Starter.java` will also parse your command line arguments and deploy your verticle. It is not supported from `Starter.java` that the commandline arguments are passed through to the verticle. The supported command line arguments can be seen with `vertx run --help`

The supported way to pass configuration params to the verticle is the the commandline switch `--conf`.

`--conf <config>                          Specifies configuration that should
                                          be provided to the verticle.
                                          <config> should reference either a
                                          text file containing a valid JSON
                                          object which represents the
                                          configuration OR be a JSON string.`

The config params can be accessed like this `Vertx.currentContext().config().arg1`

The documentation how to handle config in javascript is here: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/js/#_passing_configuration_to_a_verticle

Comment: In java its working fine but while using in javascript config() is throwing exception as undefined?

Comment: Changed the answer for javascript

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same solution, I ended up to setting environment variables.
I run the verticle with

```
VXPORT="4444" vertx run -cp xxxxx.jar path.to.MyClass
```

This is how I achieve: https://mihamina.rktmb.org/2019/06/vertx-command-line-parameters.html